# Write $D^{\alpha} f$ as a convolution

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-transform, weak-derivatives

I am trying to figure out an analysis problem related to Fourier transform and Young's convolution inequality. Here is the problem statement:

Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap L^p(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for some $1<p<\infty$. Suppose the support of $\hat{f}$ (the Fourier transform of $f$) is contained in $B(0,R)$, ball centered at zero with radius $R$. For all $p \leq r < \infty$, we have
$$\lVert D^{\alpha} f \rVert_{L^r} \leq CR^{\lvert \alpha \rvert + n(1/p-1/r)} \lVert f \rVert_{L^p} $$
(Hint: Write $D^{\alpha} f $ as a convolution and apply Young's convolution inequality.)

Young's inequality: Suppose $1 \leq p,q,r\leq \infty$ and $1+1/r=1/p+1/q$. Suppose $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g \in L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $f * g \in L^r(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and
$$ \lVert f*g \rVert_{L^r(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq \lVert f \rVert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} \lVert g \rVert_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)} $$

I am currently stuck on the first step in the hint, which is to write $D^{\alpha}f$ as a convolution.

What I have done so far is to write $D^{\alpha}f$ as
$$ D^{\alpha}f = \check{\widehat{D^{\alpha}f}} = \check{\widehat{D^{\alpha}f} \cdot \chi_{B(0,R)}} $$
where the two tiny "check" marks ("\widecheck" doesn't work...) is the inverse Fourier Transform.

Some hint on this would be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* $\hat f = \hat f \cdot \phi$, where $\phi$ is a smooth bump function satisfying $1_{B(0,R)} \le \phi \le 1_{B(0,2R)}$.

With the hint, and the property that $(f\cdot g)\check{} = \check f\ast \check g$,
\begin{align*}
f = \check{\hat f} &= (\hat f\cdot\phi)\check{} = \check{\hat f}\ast \check\phi = f\ast\check \phi.
\end{align*}
Because $\phi$ is a smooth bump function, $\check \phi$ is Schwartz, which should be good enough to plug into Young's inequality.

---

(*Notation.* For a set $E$, $1_E$ is the indicator function of $E$, equal to $1$ on $E$ and equal to $0$ on $E^c$.)

Comment: Hi, thank you for giving out the hint. I was editing my question while you answered. I have tried what you mentioned as in the edited version, and I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: @CZOnion: Do you know what taking Fourier transform of a product does? Show that $\mathscr F(f\cdot g) = \hat f\ast \hat g$. ($\mathscr F$ is the Fourier transform.)

Comment: I think what I learned was $\mathcal{F}(f*g) = \hat{f} \cdot \hat{g}$. And here, I don't quite know what the inverse Fourier transform of $\chi_{B(0,R)}$ is...

Comment: @CZOnion: Both properties are fundamental facts about the Fourier transform, and they are proved similarly. Also, there is a difference between the Fourier transform of a characteristic function of a ball and a bump function. The Fourier transform of a bump function will be Schwartz, so it will have arbitrary amounts of decay, but the Fourier transform of a characteristic function will not decay rapidly at infinity.

Comment: I see! Thank you for the clarification. Would it be possible for you to give out a bit more hints on how to write $f = \check{\hat{f}}$ with $\hat{f} = \hat{f} \cdot \phi$ as a convolution? (Sorry, I just learned this material including Schwartz functions, so I'm still a bit slow with everything)

Comment: @CZOnion: I added the formal proof of how to rewrite $f$ as a convolution with a Schwartz function. Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! Last question, how can we define $\phi$ so that $\hat{f} = \hat{f} \cdot \phi$?

Comment: Oh never mind, I think I got it. Thank you!

Comment: @CZOnion: No problem! This trick of writing a function with compact Fourier support as a convolution with a fixed Schwartz function is sometimes called the "reproducing trick".